# How to get pageindex of a gridview and add one to it in javascript

Tags: javascript, gridview

My task is to get a gridview's pageIndex and store them in a variable with adding one(1) to it

```
 var i=gridview.PageIndex +1
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
i = parseInt("<%=gridView.PageIndex %>")+1;
```